# Is heartRate data from an HKWorkoutSession a moving average?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm using an HKWorkoutSession to get heart rate data every 5 seconds in `workoutBuilder didCollectDataOf`. The heart rates are reported as "beats/minute". The question is, are they calculated as moving averages, or just over the previous time interval? (I couldn't find this specified in the documentation anywhere.)

For example, if you get the following heart rates:

```
t=0: 69 beats/min
t=5: 71 beats/min
t=10: 72 beats/min
...
```

Is each value an average of beat intervals over the past 60 seconds, or is it just extrapolated from the last 5 seconds of data?

Here's what `didCollectDataOf` looks like:

```
    func workoutBuilder(_ workoutBuilder: HKLiveWorkoutBuilder, didCollectDataOf collectedTypes: Set<HKSampleType>) {

        for type in collectedTypes {
            guard let hrType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate) else {
                return
            }

            if collectedTypes.contains(hrType) {
                if let hrQuantity = workoutBuilder.statistics(for: hrType)?.mostRecentQuantity() {
                    let hrUnit = HKUnit(from: "count/min")
                    let hr = Int(hrQuantity.doubleValue(for: hrUnit))

                    debugPrint("\(Date()) HR: \(hr)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would guess the truth lies somewhere in the middle. A heart rate of 69 would mean that the watch observed 5.75 beats over the last 5 seconds. But that is impossible, because you can only observe whole numbers (for example 5 beats or 6 beats and not a fraction) and extrapolate from that. Unless the fraction bit is based on some kind of estimate when the next beat is gonna come. If you take into account all observations over the last 60 seconds you can't pick up changes to the heart rate very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it's not a moving average.